# VBA Macro to print Columns A-J and every 40 rows

Tags: vba

I am very new to VBA Macros. I am trying to create a Macro that will set the print area for columns A-J and every 40 rows. The number of total rows will change for every worksheet but the columns will remain the same.

So far I've only been able to get the first page to print properly. This is what I have so far.

--

```
Sub formatSheets()


 For i = 40 To 1350 Step 40
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Cells(i + 1, 1)

Range("A1:J1350").Select

Next
End Sub
```

--

Thank you so much for your help.

-Mary

Comment: your code minus the `Range("A1:J1350").Select` which is not needed.  works for me.

Comment: Thanks for responding.I tried that but when i printed the sheet, it printed all the columns. I am not sure what I did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I would reset all the page-breaks and set the print area for each sheet before adding the new page-breaks.

```
Sub formatSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        ws.PageSetup.PrintArea = Intersect(.Columns("A:J"), .UsedRange)
        ws.ResetAllPageBreaks
    End With

    With ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets


        For i = 40 To 1350 Step 40
           .HPageBreaks.Add Before:=Cells(i + 1, 1)
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```